# How to use structural induction on lists?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I don't really understand structural induction and how to use it.  The question is use structural induction on lists to prove that $\DeclareMathOperator{\rev}{rev} \rev(\rev(L)) = L$. You may use the lemma
that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\app}{app}
\rev\bigl(\app(L, M)\bigr) = \app\bigl(\rev(M), \rev(L)\bigr).
$$

So far I believe the base cases are :

$L=[\;]$ and $\rev(\rev([\;]))$

But after that I am little confused as to how to go through the proof.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Structural induction goes along the *structure*. For lists, the structure is $[]$ and $x:L$ where $:$ adds a single element. Your `app` and `rev` are but *computations* on the structure, they are not structure themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, structural induction for lists $L \in \mathcal L (X)$ over a set $X$ looks something like this:
$$
  P (\,[\,]\,) \land 
  \forall x \in X , l \in \mathcal L (X) \,\big( \, P(l) \Rightarrow P(x :: l) \, \big) \implies \forall L \in \mathcal L (X) : P(L)
$$
where $P$ is any predicate on $\mathcal L (X)$.

Translated to English this induction principle tells us that in order to prove $\forall L \in \mathcal L (X), P (L)$ i.e. that "every list in $\mathcal L (X)$ had the property $P$", we need to show two things:

- $P( \, [ \, ] \, )$, meaning the empty list has the property.
- If any list $l \in \mathcal L (X)$ and element $x \in X$, we need to verify that if $l$ has the property $P$ then the extended list $x :: l$ also has the property $P$.

In your particular case, you are asked to use this for $P(L) :\iff \DeclareMathOperator{\rev}{rev} \rev(\rev(L)) = L$.